# How to make encapsulation for configuration java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have read my configuration from yml and I have also added configuration java file for my project but somehow I could not encapsulate them, I have a bit confused that how ı can make them as a private field;

my yml below;

```
conf-listener:
  listenConfForInfoEvent:
    second: 19000
  listenConfForWarnEvent:
    second: 29000
  listenConfForErrorEvent:
    second: 39000
```

my class below;

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf-listener")
public class ConfEventListenerConfiguration {

    ListenConfEvent listenConfForInfoEvent = new ListenConfEvent ();
    ListenConfEvent listenConfForWarnEvent = new ListenConfEvent ();
    ListenConfEvent listenConfForErrorEvent = new ListenConfEvent ();

   // public getter and setters

    public static class ListenConfEvent {
        int hour = 0;
        int minute = 0;
        int second = 0;
        int milliSecond = 0;

      // public getters and setters
```

Somehow I could not encapsulate them, any help

Comment: The setter and getter names must match the one from the properties. Are you sure that they are named correctly? Also those default values are not needed

Comment: Also: shouldn't that be `@Component` instead of `@Configuration`?

Comment: it is dependecy       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create object by `new` let spring do it for you. Please try below and see. If this doesn't work then you need to check if your .yaml file is well formatted and there no spacing issue.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf-listener")
public class ConfEventListenerConfiguration {

    private ListenConfEvent listenConfForInfoEvent;
    private ListenConfEvent listenConfForWarnEvent;
    private ListenConfEvent listenConfForErrorEvent;

   // public getter and setters

    public static class ListenConfEvent {
        private int second;
       // public getter and setters
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this part is there any other way ?  public static class ListenConfEvent {
        private int second;
       // public getter and setters
     }